# jQuery to display text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use the following JavaScript to display text on my page in a `<div id="st-class">`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#st-class").html("class 1");
});
```

But now I want to display a PHP value which comes from my database:

```
$res_class = mysql_result($result,$j,'class');
```

This JavaScript doesn't work:

```
$(function(){
$("#st-class").html($res_class);
});
```

Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to it this way:

```
$(function(){
  $("#st-class").html(<?php echo $res_class; ?>);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep this line in your .php file and not in js file

Also print the value inline. Not sure about php syntax. But we do like below in ASP.Net

```
$(function(){
$("#st-class").html(<%= res_class %>);
});
```

From Pedros answer, php syntax

```
$(function(){
$("#st-class").html(<?php echo $res_class; ?>);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
  $("#st-class").html(<?php echo json_encode($res_class); ?>);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the quotes.

```
$(function(){
  $("#st-class").html("<?php echo $res_class; ?>");
});
```